# C++ PBKDF2 Issue

Tags: c++, hash, pbkdf2

I have the following function:

```
void PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA_512_string(const char* pass, const char* salt, int32_t iterations, uint32_t HashLength, char* out) {
    unsigned int i;
    HashLength = HashLength / 2;
    unsigned char* digest = new unsigned char[HashLength];
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(pass, strlen(pass), (const unsigned char*)salt, strlen(salt), iterations, EVP_sha512(), HashLength, digest);
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(digest); i++) {
        sprintf(out + (i * 2), "%02x", 255 & digest[i]);
    }
}
```

When I call the function like below, I expect to get a hash back of 2400 in length, however it returns me 16:

```
char PBKDF2Hash[1025]; //\0 terminating space?
memset(PBKDF2Hash, 0, sizeof(PBKDF2Hash));
PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA_512_string("Password", "0123456789123456", 3500, 1024, PBKDF2Hash);
//PBKDF2Hash is now always 16 long -> strlen(PBKDF2Hash),
//while I expect it to be 2400 long?
//How is this possible and why is this happening?
//I can't figure it out
```

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of how PBKDF2 works, I would suggest researching that first.

Comment: @Mgetz, in my opinion I know how it works. I had it working returning me a 1024 length string however I switched to MSVC and now it keeps returning me a 16 length string? So how is this able to happen and what did I misunderstood about PBKDF2?

Comment: "The derived key will be written to out. The size of the out buffer is specified via keylen" the size of the buffer is not the size of the resultant key which is based on the hash. The difference is that windows zeros memory in most cases when using `new` and array syntax, or perhaps you just happened to get a page that had been previously zeroed.

Comment: side note: this was always a variable thing because hashes can return null bytes, you can't use `strlen` on them.

Comment: @Mgetz, right. So how can I fix this? I indeed changed the digest initialization in order to compile with MSVC from `unsigned char* digest[HashLength];` into `unsigned char* digest = new unsigned char[HashLength]`. Is that what is giving me this unexpected behavior?

Comment: not unexpected at all, although you are flirting with "undefined behavior" in your code for other reasons. The output of a PBKDF2 run is determined by the hash algorithm which in this case is sha512, which produces a 512 bit result or 64bytes.  Although the fact you're getting back 16 would indicate to me that you're probably not passing in the hash you think you are.

Comment: @Mgetz, what are you referring to with 'hash', since it takes a password and salt?

Comment: @Mgetz, when I increase both the salt and password size and length (which I validate in the function and is identical), the output stays 16 still. So, the output is the hash right? So what do you mean with your last phrase  "you're probably not passing in the hash you think you are". I also use meest to clear the hash as you can see at my edited question `memset(PBKDF2Hash, 0, sizeof(PBKDF2Hash));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `digest` is a `pointer`, `sizeof(digest)` will not give the length of the array. Depending on different platforms, `sizeof(digest)` may give you 4 or 8, which is not what you want. Maybe you should use `for (i = 0; i < HashLength; i++)`.

Another unrelated issue of your code is that, `digest` is not deleted in `PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA_512_string`, which causes `memory leak`

Comment: Oke, but how should I change `digest[i]` within that for loop you are referring to with changing the range by `HashLength`? Since the `digest[i]` won't reach the same range as `HashLength` will? Should I use `delete digest` at the end of the function?

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren, I don't follow. What do you mean by change digest[i], I don't see it's changed in the loop.

Comment: Well you tell me to increase the upper limit of the for loop right? Within the loop the function also uses digest[i], what should I do if I change the upper limit to the HashLength with the digest within the loop itself?

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren, I guess you don't need to change anything else. But I am not 100% sure since I do not fully understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Have a look within the for loop for the sprintf command which works with digest[i]. This range won't be as long as the HashLength range right? So I will also have to change that or will it be long enough?

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren, what range are you talking about? Does this range mean out? digest's length is  HashLength, out's length is 2 * HashLength. Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren, have you ever tried your code after my suggestion, is the output what you expected?

Comment: I can't validate this right now, but I will try your solution within 2 days. However, I expect that HashLength outranges the digest[i]. But I'm not sure so I will have to validate this

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren, What do you mean by "HashLength outranges digest[i]"? Why are you even comparing them. HashLength is the length of digest, digest[i] is just an element of the array.

Comment: So the problem you define is just that sizeof(digest) for the upper limit of the for loop is the whole issue? I can increase this by HashLength without a problem?

Comment: I just validated the encryption changing the upper for loop limit with HashLength, which returns me an encrypted string of the requested length again. Great work! Thanks